# QGIS dies at startup (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: qgis

When I start qgis with the terminal I get the following error:

```
QGIS died on signal 11[New LWP 15278] [New LWP 15279] [New LWP 15280] [New LWP 15283] [New LWP 15284] [New LWP 15286] [New LWP 15292] [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled] Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1". 0x00007fa1f82b96c2 in __GI___waitpid (pid=15293, stat_loc=0x7fff74e3b6ac, options=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:30 30   ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c: No such file or directory. [Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7fa1fc1a5980 (LWP 15275))]
#0  0x00007fa1f82b96c2 in __GI___waitpid (pid=15293, stat_loc=0x7fff74e3b6ac, options=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:30
        resultvar = 18446744073709551104
        sc_cancel_oldtype = 0
#1  0x000055c5eb4217ce in  ()
#2  0x00007fa1f8213f20 in <signal handler called> () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007fa1f835a5ab in __strncmp_sse42 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse42.S:270
#4  0x00007fa1ec4b5d77 in pj_param_exists () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.13
#5  0x00007fa1ec4c99b4 in proj_create () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.13
#6  0x00007fa1f6dd8a67 in  () at /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20
#7  0x00007fa1f6dc8520 in OGRSpatialReference::importFromProj4(char const*) () at /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20
#8  0x00007fa1fa957244 in QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem::setProj4String(QString const&) () at /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.3.4.3
#9  0x00007fa1fa95a2e5 in QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem::createFromProj4(QString const&) () at /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.3.4.3
#10 0x00007fa1fa95b01c in QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem::fromProj4(QString const&) () at /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.3.4.3
#11 0x00007fa1fa9a7f40 in QgsEllipsoidUtils::ellipsoidParameters(QString const&) () at /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.3.4.3
#12 0x00007fa1faa6cfbb in QgsMapSettings::setEllipsoid(QString const&) () at /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.3.4.3
#13 0x00007fa1f649071a in  () at /usr/lib/libqgis_gui.so.3.4.3
#14 0x00007fa1f8e206cf in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#15 0x00007fa1faf44845 in QgsProject::ellipsoidChanged(QString const&) () at /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.3.4.3
#16 0x00007fa1faaf48db in QgsProject::setEllipsoid(QString const&) () at /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.3.4.3
#17 0x00007fa1fb601172 in QgisApp::fileNew(bool, bool) () at /usr/lib/libqgis_app.so.3.4.3
#18 0x00007fa1fb615e92 in QgisApp::QgisApp(QSplashScreen*, bool, bool, QString const&, QString const&, QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>) () at /usr/lib/libqgis_app.so.3.4.3
#19 0x000055c5eb41d5d5 in  ()
#20 0x00007fa1f81f6b97 in __libc_start_main (main=0x55c5eb41b760, argc=1, argv=0x7fff74e3d998, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fff74e3d988) at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
        result = <optimized out>
        unwind_buf = {cancel_jmp_buf = {{jmp_buf = {0, -8979781846726237085, 94308543893936, 140735154477456, 0, 0, -2948634281101908893, -2906720311133100957}, mask_was_saved = 0}}, priv = {pad = {0x0, 0x0, 0x7fa1fc013733 <_dl_init+259>, 0x7fa1fbfd1538}, data = {prev = 0x0, cleanup = 0x0, canceltype =
-67029197}}}
        not_first_call = <optimized out>
#21 0x000055c5eb4211da in _start () gdb returned 0 Aborted`
```

No idea what is happening.

I had some problems in the installation, I had to create a fake gdal-abi-2-2-3 package and had to install grass-core_7.4.0-1_amd64 instead of grass-core_7.4.3 for dependency problems with Virtual package grass740.

Answer (score 3):

I had no issue installing on 18.04 using the instructions at http://qgis.org.

/etc/apt/sources

```
deb https://qgis.org/debian bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
deb-src https://qgis.org/debian bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
```

then

```
sudo update
sudo upgrade
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

and all was fine, including gdal and grass.

```
$ apt list gdal-*
Listing... Done
gdal-bin/bionic,bionic,now 2.2.3+dfsg-2 amd64 [installed]
gdal-data/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 2.2.3+dfsg-2 all [installed]
$ apt list grass 
Listing... Done
grass/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic 7.4.0-1 all
$ apt list grass-core
Listing... Done
grass-core/bionic,bionic,now 7.4.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Comment: Yes, I first tried with these instructions, but I got the errors above commented. :(

Comment: try `apt purge grass qgis gdal` before you start